# using sed with ampersand (&)

Tags: sed, quoting, replace

I'm using sed to find and replace patterns within SAS files I have rather than changing them individually. The problem is I am trying to replace macro variables and when I use the ampersand it is not processing correctly.

```
Here's my code:
sed -ie 's/user=&uid./user=&sysuserid./g' *_table_*.sas
```

whenever I run this command it seems to append and do all kinds of funky stuff with the original text.

Question: How do I replace text that contains ampersands with sed command?

Comment: `&` is a special character so it needs to be escaped when used in the RHS - in your case you have to run  `'s/user=&uid./user=\&sysuserid./g'` although I suspect you also need to escape the dot in the LHS to match a literal dot so you actually need `'s/user=&uid\./user=\&sysuserid./g'`

Comment: yes, '&' on the right basically means "everything that matched on the left", so escape it with '\'. You should make that the answer, rather than just a comment.

Comment: i didnt have to escape the first period...just a heads up in anyone else was curious :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`&` is special in the replacement text: it means “the whole part of the input that was matched by the pattern”, so what you're doing here replaces `user=&uidX` with `user=user=&uidXsysuserid.`. To insert an actual ampersand in the replacement text, use `\&`.

Another thing that looks wrong is that `.` in the search pattern stands for any character (except a newline), but the `.` at the end of the replacement text is a literal dot. If you want to replace only the literal string `user=&uid.`, protect the `.` with a backslash.

```
sed -e 's/user=&uid\./user=\&sysuserid./g'
```

If you want to replace any one character and preserve it in the result, put the character in a group and use `\1` in the replacement to refer to that group.

```
sed -e 's/user=&uid\(.\)/user=\&sysuserid\1/g'
```

In fact, given the repetition between the original text and the replacement, you should use groups anyway:

```
sed -e 's/\(user=&\)u\(id\.\)/\1sysuser\2/g'
```

i.e. “replace `u` by `sysuser` between `user=&` and `id.`”.

Comment: could you explain groups?

Comment: @lucasdavis500 A group identifies a part of the pattern. It's delimited by backslash-parentheses. For example `\(user=&\)` is a pattern that matches `user&` and stores the match string as a group (group number 1 since it's the first group in the pattern). Then in the replacement `\1` is replaced by the string stored for group number 1.

Comment: do you mean \(user=&\) stores user=&, not user&?

Comment: @lucasdavis500 I don't understand your comment. The character `=` in regular expressions and in replacement text stands for itself, so `user=&` matches only `user=&`, and `user=&` in the replacement text yields `user=` followed by the part of the line matched by the regex.

Comment: are you saying "=" is treated differently? I don't understand what you mean by \(user=&\) in the search will find the pattern user&. My search is for "user=&uid." and replacing it with "user=&sysuserid." how does replacing "user=&" with "user&" work? this code worked with my replacement text and maintained the "=" symbol. The way you described it leads me to believe it would not do so...maybe I'm reading it wrong

Comment: or do you mean by your second comment that user=& in the replacement text yields user= because of the fact that "&" is treated differently in the replacement text without escaping it with a \.

Comment: @lucasdavis500 The `=` character does not have any special meaning. `user=&` in the replacement text produces `user=` followed by the original matched text. `user=\&` in the replacement text produces `user=&`