# How do you remove all punctuation using the sed command?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove all punctuation from a text file using the `sed` command, but I don't quite know how to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using sed with ampersand (&)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/using-sed-with-ampersand)

Answer (score 4):

If by "punctuation", you mean any of the characters in the set

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

(which is the set of "POSIX punctuation characters", written as `[:punct:]` in a regular expression) and if by "remove" you mean "delete completely", then it would be more efficient to do this with `tr` like so:

```bsh
tr -d '[:punct:]' <file.in >file.out
```

This tells `tr` to delete all characters from the above set in its input stream, reading from a file called `file.in` and writing the result to some file `file.out`.

With `sed`, you would do the same thing with

```bsh
sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' <file.in >file.out
```

... but I would expect this to be slightly slower (possibly only noticeably so on large input data).

Comment: Though I in this case I'm usually interested in the words and replace the punctuation with spaces or new lines, as this makes the result better processable. So: tr '[[:punct:]]' ' ' or tr '[[:punct:]]' '\n' might help the OP better.

Comment: @JdeHaan The user in the question did not further specify what they wanted to do beyond removing the punctuation. Your `tr` command would be more correct if written as `tr '[:punct:]' '[\n*]'` (see the `tr` manual for that syntax).